# Индексация изображения поисковиком, но не загрузка их браузером

Tags: javascript, html, lazyloading

При той же отложенной загрузки изображений мы имеем в исходном коде изображение без (с пустым) `src`, например:

```
<img src='' data-src='http://example.com/img.jpg'>
```

Скажем JS скриптом в нужный момент мы подставим в `src` URL из другого атрибута и браузер её загрузит.

Такое поведение нам необходимо. Однако поисковики такие изображения не индексируют.

Как добиться того, чтобы изображение было проиндексировано поисковиком, но не загружено браузером пользователя?

Comment: А вы не рассматривали вариант генерировать src на сервере через скрипт , в зависимости от user-agent?

Answer (score 1):

Так как поисковые боты не могут в javascript, можно выдать им картинки в теге `<noscript>` (очевидно, такие картинки увидят ещё и пользователи, отключившие javascript)

```
<noscript>
    <img src='http://example.com/img.jpg' alt='крутая картинка' title='крутая картинка'>
</noscript>

<img src='' data-src='http://example.com/img.jpg'>
```

Alt и title помогут поисковикам понять, о чём картинки.

Можно, в принципе, определять поисковых ботов по user-agent, но выдача разного контента поисковым ботам и людям может выйти боком (в теории).